# Plotting multiple graph using for loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, matplotlib

I have 35 subjects in total and I'm trying to make a separate graph for each one using for loop, but my code is giving me one dense graph with all the subjects.

```
all_subnames = final['sub'].unique() # this shows all the subjects 1-35

[for i in all_subnames:
    print(i)
    subs = final\[final\['sub'\]== i\]
    sns.lineplot(x = subs.index.values,y = subs\['RT'\])][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a new figure and axis for each iteration in for loop.
 This is one way to do it.

```
import seaborn as sns

## made up date with 10 rows, 5 columns
y = np.random.randint(low=1,high=10,size=(10,5))

# iterate over the data
for item in range(y.shape[1]):

    # create a new figure and axis object  
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    # give this axis to seaborn so that it can plot in each iteration
    sns.lineplot(np.arange(y.shape[0]) ,y[:,item], ax = ax)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you open a new figure for every plot:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn

all_subnames = final['sub'].unique() # this shows all the subjects 1-35

for i in all_subnames:
    print(i)
    subs = final\[final\['sub'\]== i\]

    # Creates a new figure for the plot of the subject
    plt.figure()
    sns.lineplot(x = subs.index.values,y = subs\['RT'\])][1]
```